# Exporting scraped data to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get data from a website that requires me to follow 2 URLs before scraping the data.

The goal is to get an exported file that looks like this:

[image: clean data in the spreadsheet with no spaces or gaps]

My code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy import Request

class myItems(Item):
    info1 = Field()
    info2 = Field()
    info3 = Field()
    info4 = Field()

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'techbot'
    start_urls = ['']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Extracts first link
        items = []

        list1 = response.css("").extract() #extract all info from here

        for i in list1:
            link1 = 'https:...' + str(i)
            request = Request(link1, self.parseInfo1, dont_filter =True)
            request.meta['item'] = items
            yield request

        yield items

    def parseInfo1(self, response):
        #Extracts second link
        item = myItems()
        items = response.meta['item']

        list1 = response.css("").extract()
        for i in list1:
            link1 = '' + str(i)
            request = Request(link1, self.parseInfo2, dont_filter =True)
            request.meta['item'] = items
            items.append(item)
            return request

    def parseInfo2(self, response):
        #Extracts all data
        item = myItems()
        items = response.meta['item']
        item['info1'] = response.css("").extract()
        item['info2'] = response.css("").extract()
        item['info3'] = response.css("").extract()
        item['info4'] = response.css("").extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

I've executed the spider in the terminal with the command:

```
scrapy crawl techbot
```

The data I get is out of order, and with gaps like this:
[image: out of order data]

For example it scrapes the first set of data multiple times and the rest is out of order.

If anyone could point me in the direction to get the results in a cleaner format as shown in the beginning that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use `print()` to see what is going on in code - see what/when you get in variables.

Comment: if you add real url then we can test it and see problem.  Currently it is impossible.

Comment: shouldn't you use `yield` instead of `return` with `Request` ?

Comment: I think in `parseInfo2` you could `yield/return` single `item`. I don't know why you use list `items = []`.

Comment: you get list `list1 = response.css("").extract()` and later you replace it with `link1 = 'https:...' + str(i)` - why ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by consolidating the following of both links into one function instead of two. My spider is working now as follows:

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'techbot'
start_urls = ['']

def parse(self, response):
    #Extracts links
    items = []

    list1 = response.css("").extract()
    for i in list1:
        link1 = 'https:...' + str(i)
        request = Request(link2, self.parse, dont_filter =True)
        request.meta['item'] = items
        yield request

    list2 = response.css("").extract()
    for i in list2:
        link2 = '' + str(i)
        request = Request(link1, self.parseInfo2, dont_filter =True)
        request.meta['item'] = items
        yield request

    yield items

def parseInfo2(self, response):
    #Extracts all data
    item = myItems()
    items = response.meta['item']
    item['info1'] = response.css("").extract()
    item['info2'] = response.css("").extract()
    item['info3'] = response.css("").extract()
    item['info4'] = response.css("").extract()
    items.append(item)
    return items
```